# C++ Function, take in enum and return a typedef class type to be used in template?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to write an (inline?) C++ function, where we accept an enum as input and returns a class type which can be used in a template declaration?

My intuition is that since there are a finite number of enum types, it should be possible?

```
enum MyEnumType { A, B, C };

class MyClassA { };
class MyCLassB { };
class MyClassB { };

template class<T>
class ATemplatedClass {
  // ...
};

NotSureWhatReturnType ConvertEnumToClassType(MyEnumType type) {
  switch (type) {
     case A: return MyClassA;
     case B: return MyClassB;
     case C: return MyClassC:
     default: throw;
  }
}

MyEnumType type = GottenSomewhere();

auto class_type = ConvertEnumToClassType(type);

ATemplatedClass<class_type> is_this_possible;
```

Comment: Maybe you want to look into polymorphic class hierarchies and factories?

Comment: You should explain the **real** problem that you want to solve, rather than the intended solution. What you are asking cannot be done directly, but there are other things that might fit the problem (traits that map from the enum to a type, for example)

Answer (score 3):

Functions cannot return types. You need a [metafunction](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Metafunction):

```
template <MyEnumType>
struct ConvertEnumToClassType;

template <>
struct ConvertEnumToClassType<A> {
    typedef MyClassA type;
};

template <>
struct ConvertEnumToClassType<B> {
    typedef MyClassB type;
};

// … etc.

typedef ConvertEnumToClassType<A> class_type;

ATemplatedClass<class_type> is_this_possible;
```

Of course this only works at compile time (since that’s when templates are resolved).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few approaches.

First, if you know the `enum` at compile time, you can create a metafunction that takes the `enum` as a template argument and return the tyoe as expected.

If you do not, there are a few approaches.

First, you can do a magic switch, where you take a functor and invoke it with the runtime-determined `enum` value.  Amusingly this is best done by first implementing the above metafunction solution.

A second approach is type erasure.  You return an object that is externally uniform, but inside it knows that it has a particular type.  As an exampke, `boost::variant`.  Now accessing that internal tyoe can involve the above solution (`boost` visitor like), or maybe a `virtual` or `std::function` interface that stores the different behavior internally.

Finally, you can use the magic switch technique by mapping the runtime `enum` into a compile time `enum` (instead of a type) and just use the fist technique.

The magic switch technique is not all that magic.  Write a switch statement and in each case invoke a template functor with a type or compile time constant. To make it fancy, take the 'body' of the switch as a template parameter, and maybe even use some metaprogramming to generate the switch code via nested `if` or an array lookup.  Those advanced techniques are not required.

Answer (score 1):

Use a template and specialize:

```
template <MyEnumType> struct ConvertEnum;

template <> struct ConvertEnum<A> { typedef MyClassA type; };
template <> struct ConvertEnum<B> { typedef MyClassB type; };
template <> struct ConvertEnum<C> { typedef MyClassC type; };
```

Usage:

```
ConvertEnum<A>::type x;
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but this solution will only work if the type is known at compile time? e.g., if the enum type was acquired at runtime it wouldn't work?

Comment: @user2570384: Well yes. That's why they call C++ *statically* typed. It's not just that it wouldn't work. The entire question wouldn't make any sense if you didn't know the enum at compile time.